# ReduxToolKit | CreateEntityAdaptor userSelectors.selectAll giving Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, createentityadapter

Hi i am using ReduxToolKit CreateEntityAdaptor for crud, when i get all users from API by using userSelectors.selectAll, it gives "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".

let me show my API response.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Admin",
            "email": "admin@admin.com",
            "assigned_roles": [
                "Administrator"
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-10-06T20:08:32.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://laravel-api.test/api/users?page=1",
        "last": "http://laravel-api.test/api/users?page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "links": [
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "&laquo; Previous",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "http://laravel-api.test/api/users?page=1",
                "label": "1",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "Next &raquo;",
                "active": false
            }
        ],
        "path": "http://laravel-api.test/api/users",
        "per_page": 15,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

1. using AsyncThunk for getting data from API services/userService file

   import { createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import axios from "axios";
   import { API_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN } from "../constants";

   ```
    export const  fetchUsers =  createAsyncThunk(
        'user/fetchUsers',
        async (page) => {
        const data = await axios(API_URL+'/users?page='+page,
          {   method:'GET',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
              },
          });
          return data.data;
        }

      )
   ```
2. features/userSlice.js

   import { createSlice, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import { HTTP_STATUS } from "../constants";
   import { fetchUsers } from "../services/userService";

   ```
    const userAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
        selectId: (user) => user.id,
    });

    const userSlice = createSlice({
        name: "user",
        initialState: {
            loading: false,
            status: null,
            message: "",
        },
        reducers:{
            pageByNumber: (state,{payload}) => {
              state.page = payload.page
            },
            nextPage: (state, {payload}) => {
              state.page = state.page++
            },
            previousPage: (state, {payload}) => {
              state.page = state.page--
            },
            clear: (state) => {
              state.status = null
              state.message = null
            }
          },
        extraReducers: {
          [fetchUsers.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
            state.status = HTTP_STATUS.PENDING
          },
          [fetchUsers.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            console.log(payload.data);
            state.loading = false
            state.page = payload.meta.current_page
            state.total_pages = Math.ceil(payload.meta.total/payload.meta.per_page)
            userAdapter.setAll(state, payload.data)
            state.status = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED
          },
          [fetchUsers.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.status = HTTP_STATUS.REJECTED
          },
        },
      });

      export const userSelectors = userAdapter.getSelectors(
        (state) => state.user
        )
      export const {pageByNumber, nextPage, previousPage,clear} = userSlice.actions
      export default userSlice.reducer
   ```
3. views/users/index.js
   [image]

i am not getting understand why there is map array error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got the answer actually i had not passed my initial state to create Entity Adapter, below i have shown latest code for initial state.

```
 initialState: userAdapter.getInitialState({ //Initial state should be wrapped in Adapter
        loading: false,
        status: null,
        message: "",
    }),
```